# Setting the Monero blockchain location on macOS with monerod

Tags: monero-wallet-gui, monerod, monero-wallet-cli, macos

I downloaded the macOS Monero GUI wallet and did a full node sync to an external SSD. I then started looking into the Monero CLI wallet and thought it would be useful for scripting some tasks.

Now I can use the monerod CLI app to keep my node synced, but I'm not sure how to tell which directory to save and load the blockchain from.

I couldn't see an appropriate command when I ran:

```
monerod help
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify where to put the blockchain folder (plus peer data, logs, SSL files, etc) with the `--data-dir` option. For example, the command:

```
monerod --data-dir Desktop/monerodir
```

would put all the daemon files into the directory Desktop/monerodir.

Comment: Thank you very much!